# Simple conditional operator optimization

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have a repetitive set of instructions that I would like to optimize. Is there a better pattern to achieve the same goal but with less repetition ?

```
var assigned = this.state.data ? this.state.data.assigned : 1,
delivered = this.state.data ? this.state.data.delivered : 1,
unassigned = this.state.data ? this.state.data.unassigned : 1,
pending = this.state.data ? this.state.data.pending: 1,
total = this.state.data ? this.state.data.total: 1,
failed = this.state.data ? this.state.data.failed : 1;
```

Comment: I dont think why people's are downvoting without proper explanation

Comment: I don't know how this lacks context. This *is* the code - a series of assignments that are each a ternary expression. The goal is to have this effect without being that verbose.

Comment: @VLAZ It's all explained in the [help/on-topic]. We don't review snippets. There's a long list of reasons for that, which can all be found on meta.

Comment: @Mast I still don't get it. As far as I can see, this example answers "yes" to each of the criteria listed. There is code, OP is presumably the author or maintainer, seems to be from an actual project, it works as intended, OP wants this to be "good code" as in improved, all facets can be discussed and I've indeed made suggestions not directly related to OP's request. Sure, it's a *short* code but I don't see *length* being mentioned. The only thing I see it *maybe* failing is the "Do not ask 'How do I best do X'" but if it's *that* reason there could have been an edit or comment.

Comment: @Mast wait, upon review, are you saying that it should have just been executable code? That's also addressable through a comment or edit, I would think. A downvote + close vote with no explanation for an easily correctable issue doesn't address this. Not to mention that the help centre doesn't make it sound like an absolute requirement - just an option.

Comment: @VLAZ The help center is phrased too friendly, yes. However, given the current course of SE on trying to be friendly instead of preferring clarity, that is not going to change.

Comment: @Mast so, let's review "there is a problem here" -> "what is the problem?" -> "there is a problem here". I'm baffled by the complete lack of information here. Is this really a network where people, you know, give feedback?

Comment: The problem is that the code is presented without context. It is hard to give the proper advice unless we see where the `state` values come from and how they are used.

Comment: @200_success I'm not sure why it would matter. To me the code is completely clear - it's a bog standard null-safe extraction of a value with a fallback. Where the value goes afterwards doesn't seem relevant, nor where it comes from as long as the general shape of the source object is known.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can use the OR operand. It's idiomatic to mean "either get the value of a variable or a fallback value, if falsey"

```
assignment = someVariable || "fallback value"
```

Since you're checking `this.state.data` every time, it's better to either check it once

```
const data = this.state.data || {}
```

and then use that

```
var assigned = data.assigned || 1,
    delivered = data.delivered || 1,
    unassigned = data.unassigned || 1,
    pending = data.pending || 1,
    total = data.total || 1,
    failed = data.failed || 1;
```

This will leave `this.state.data` untouched, you are just working with a *different* variable called `data`.

Alternatively, you can directly check and possibly initialise `this.state.data`, assuming that doesn't lead to problems with any other potential initialisation.

```
this.state.data = this.state.data || {}
```

and then you can check `var assigned = this.state.data.assigned || 1` and so on.

Note that this style will give you the fallback if the current value is *falsey*. This includes an empty string or the number zero. If those are valid values, then you should not be using the OR operator to get them. For example, with `this.state.data.failed = 0` the expression `failed = this.state.data.failed || 1` will give you `1`. In that case, you might need to write a custom function to get the value or get a default value. If you have Lodash, you can use [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) for that purpose.

If you are using ES6, then this can be drastically shortened using a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with default values

```js
const data = { assigned: 5, delivered: 10, total: 42 };

let { 
  assigned = 1, 
  delivered = 1, 
  unassigned = 1, 
  pending = 1, 
  total = 1, 
  failed = 1 
} = data;

console.log("assigned", assigned);
console.log("delivered", delivered);
console.log("unassigned", unassigned);
console.log("pending", pending);
console.log("total", total);
console.log("failed", failed);
```

Comment: It would be useful to know what is wrong with this question/answer if we are to improve them.